# PJAX javascript standalone unable to execute jQuery after ajax load

Tags: jquery, pjax

I'm using the Standalone version of PJAX found here: https://github.com/thybag/PJAX-Standalone

It works fantastic, the jQuery-PJAX doesn't work for me hence, the standalone usage. Now, what the problem is;

Upon completion of the loaded content into my div who's id is `pageContent`, the content inside has elements styled by jQuery. these elements are not rendering as the jQuery is not being fired upon completion.

Any ways to do this? [This SO Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358003/run-jquery-ready-block-again-after-ajax-loaded) helps the jQuery version out. I wondered if there was any way to implement this in the standalone version?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your trying to get a bit of code to run every time a page is loaded in by PJAX, you're best bet is probably to make use of either the complete or success callback.

Something like:

```
pjax.connect({
    'container': 'pageContent',
    'complete': function(e){ 
        // Whatever jQuery code you want to apply to #pageContent here
        $("#pageContent").find('a').addClass("link");
    },
});
```